# Chance of same family winning first and second lottery prize

Tags: probability

Let's keep it simple. The same family, pick the same euro millions numbers (odds [here](https://www.lottery.co.uk/euromillions/odds))

minus one star number, which means they would win second prize. I calculated this as two independent combined events, and did $\frac{1}{139,838,160}\cdot\frac{1}{6,991,908}$ = 1 in ~977 trillion. But I guess the definition of dependent/independent events is causing some doubt here.

Comment: If they have picked the **same** numbers, **both**  will either get or not get .

Answer (score 1):

You have calculated the (approximate) odds of a specific family winning first and second prizes ater buying only two tickets (actually, your result should be multiplied by 2, but never mind). But (i) there are many many families in Europe, and (ii) many of these families buy more than two tickets. So your result doesn't mean very much.

Answer (score 0):

That looks about right. To determine if they're independent, you need to consider whether the odds of the second winning the lottery is still $\frac{1}{6,991,908}$ even after the first wins the lottery. Ie that the outcome where the first wins the lottery doesn't affect the outcome where the second wins it.